# Matlab Cross-Validation error in calculating performance of model

Tags: matlab, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to perform cross-validation on my models with multiple classification classes but I am getting errors when trying to update my classperf on each fold. I am getting this error "Index vector has invalid values."

My code is as below:

```
K = 5; 
N = size(DataSet, 1); 
idx = crossvalind('Kfold', N, K); 
cp = classperf(trainLabel);
for i = 1:K
     ... 
     %Long codes for svmtrain & svmclassify
     ...
     cp = classperf(cp, Group, trueTestLabel); %error on this line
end
cp.CorrectRate
```

where trainLabel is a 120 x 1 double consisting of the ground-truth score for all of the items; Group is the results obtained from svmclassify in 20 x 1 double; and trueTestLabel is the ground-truth score for the testing class in 20 x 1 double form obtained using the following function:

```
trueTestLabel = trainLabel(idx == i, end);
```

I have tried converting "Group" and "trueTestLabel" into cells by using num2cell function as such:

```
 cp = classperf(cp, num2cell(Group), num2cell(trueTestLabel ));
```

but instead, I got a different error saying "When the class labels of the CP object are numeric, the output
of the classifier must be all non-negative integers or NaN's."

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. Apparently after reading the documentation for [classperf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/classperf.html) multiple times, I found out the problem lies in my "testidx" from the function

```
classperf(CP, classout, testidx);
```

where previously I was using

```
cp = classperf(cp, Group, trueTestLabel);
```

and the trueTestLabel is the ground-truth score for the testing class in 20 x 1 double form. Basically, from the documentation, it states that testidx is the observations that were used in the current validation instead of the actual ground-truth score of the model.

I have understood the documentation incorectly and thus was facing the problem mentioned above. I fixed it by modifying the line into

```
cp = classperf(cp, Group, idx == i);
```

and it works now. Please correct me if I am still using the wrong approach. Thanks.